# How local time zone can be used in corda 4 other than UTC

Tags: corda

Tried to add TimeWindow in corda transaction.

But the time returned by java INSTANT is UTC time. When testing the cordapp in local test network creates exception.

How local time zone can be used in corda 4 other than UTC for specify in TimeWindow

Answer (score 0):

I think `TimeWindow` only accepts `Instant` objects as inputs, so you can't use local time zones. You can use a different reference clock for generating `Instant` objects with a UTC offset in Java (see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Type_How_to/Date_Timezone/Change_Instant_to_various_timezone.htm) for an example).

What kind of exception are you getting?